# Updating selenium through 'sudo pip install -U selenium' fails

Tags: python, macos, selenium, installation, pip

I'm trying to update selenium through the shell command:

```
sudo pip install -U selenium
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
    Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 732, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 835, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 376, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 315, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/selenium'
```

I don't know what the system is trying to tell me with this line:

> OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
> '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/selenium'

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and then installing again: `sudo pip uninstall selenium` and then `sudo pip install selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

This worked for me: go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads and download selenium-3.0.1.tar.gz.

Then:

```
tar zxvf selenium-3.0.1.tar.gz
cd selenium-3.0.1
sudo python setup.py install
```